# OnSubmit not working in form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following component being returned by render function:

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.filter(e)}>
            <Modal className='side-modal' show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.hide}>
                <Scrollbars autoHide>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Filter</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <ControlLabel>Search Based On Keywords</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl value={this.state.searchInput} type='text' placeholder='Legal Entity Name, DBA Name, Email or Processor Submerchant ID' onChange={this.setInputSearchText} />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <ControlLabel>Account Status</ControlLabel>
                            <CustomSelect
                                selectID={'accountStatus'}
                                hasListIcon={true}
                                listItemDetails={this.state.itemList}
                                defaultItemObj={this.state.defaultItem}
                                isReset={this.state.isReset}
                                setValue={this.setAccountStatusValue}
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Scrollbars>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button bsStyle='primary' type='submit'>
                        <span className='icon ion-checkmark icon--inner'></span> Apply
        </Button>
                    <Button type='reset' onClick={this.resetFilter}>
                        <span className='icon ion-android-refresh icon--inner'></span> Reset
        </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </form>
```

I wanted the form to call **filter** function on clicking 'Enter' from keyboard but it doesn't seem to work, even onSubmit isnot called when clicked on **Apply**. What might be the problem here? Thank you in advance.
Here is my filter function:

```
filter = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.getSomeReults();
    this.props.hide();
}
```

Comment: Can you also write up the filter function? @skaranjit

Comment: Are you calling `e.preventDefault();` inside filter function?

Comment: Yes i have added that.

Comment: Can you put the form inside modal?

Comment: Its not working. There seems to be some other problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-bootstrap) for modal and as per what i can see each component i.e. Modal Header, Modal Body, Modal Footer are separate. So your code i.e.

```
<form onSubmit={ e => this.filter(e) } >
</form>
```

should come inside

```
<ModalBody>
//Form code here
</ModalBody>
```